# Device, do not send emails confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When a user sign up or reconfirm, email is not sent. I can not understand where the error, what do I look for? How me check? Please, help, thank you.

**Auth.rb**

```
module Models::User::Auth
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # acts_as_authentic do |c|
    #   c.validates_length_of_login_field_options :in => 1..50
    #   c.validates_format_of_login_field_options :with => /\A[[[:alnum:]]\.+\-_\p{S}@\u2020]([[[:alnum:]]\.+\-_\p{S}@ ]+)?[[[:alnum:]]\.+\-_\p{S}@\u2020]?$/u
    # end

    attr_accessor :login

    attr_accessor :terms
    validates :terms, acceptance: true, if: Proc.new { |user| user.new_record? }

    attr_accessor :current_password
    # attr_accessor :reset_password
    # validate :validate_current_password, if: :changes_password?
    # validates :email, format: /\A(\S+)@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.)([a-z]{2,4})(\.?)([a-z]{0,4})+\z/

    attr_accessible :username, :email, :login, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :terms, :current_password, :reset_password

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
           :token_authenticatable, :async, :encryptable, :confirmable  #, :omniauthable

    scope :confirmed, where(:confirmed_at.not_eq => nil)
    scope :unconfirmed, where(confirmed_at: nil)    
  end

  def unconfirmed?
    confirmed_at == nil
  end

  def not_deleted?
    deleted_at.nil?
  end

  def active_for_authentication?
    # Uncomment the below debug statement to view the properties of the returned self model values.
    # logger.debug self.to_yaml

    super && not_deleted?
  end

  def inactive_message
    not_deleted? ? super : :special_condition_is_not_valid
  end

  # module ClassMethods
  #   def find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  #     conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  #     if login = conditions.delete(:login)
  #       where(conditions).
  #         where('lower(username) = :v OR lower(email) = :v', v: login.downcase).first
  #     else
  #       where(conditions).first
  #     end
  #   end
  # end

  protected

  def changes_password?
    not new_record? and password.present?  #and not reset_password
  end

  def validate_current_password
    errors.add(:current_password, :invalid) unless valid_password?(current_password)
  end
end
```

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "127.0.0.1", :port => 1025 }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3666' } 
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

**controllers/confirmations_controller.rb**

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  def new
    super
    resource.login = current_user.email if user_signed_in?
  end



  protected

  def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    if user_signed_in?
      home_path
    else
      new_session_path(resource_name)
    end if is_navigational_format?
  end

  # The path used after confirmation.
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    '/profile'
  end
end
```

Comment: To what e-mail are you trying to send the email? And also, did the folder `"tmp/letter_opener` created after sending an email?

Comment: in Deviser.rb:
    config.mailer_sender = "my_mail@gmail.com"

Comment: I meant `to` what email is email sent, not from which email

Comment: tmp/letter_opener,  no. dont  created

Comment: easy, my mail on gmail. haensch.berlin@gmail.com

Comment: Also, why using `localhost:3666`? Is there any purpose of changing the port?

Comment: becose site open on local server with http://localhost:3666/. What change?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Issue was with delayed_job. I solved by setting delayed job.

Comment: You could have added the actual reason for it, and what have you changed, and not just to put - solved by setting delayed job, considering the people who were involved in solving `YOUR` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I am getting an notification not to chat via comments o.O :) so I am will post suggestions here :)

When you run rails app the default port is `3000`. In order to run it on different port you have to manually specify it. 
I would suggest to try to run in on port `3000`, and change the line:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3666' }
```

to:

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Maybe the letter opener is watching the default port `3000` and not
some 'custom' one

Comment: how me change application port from 3666 to 3000?

Comment: @StefanHansch, could you test sending an email by running the server with `rails s -p 3000` and then we could see if we need to change the port in the first place ?